# index and length must refer to a location within the string. parameter name length

Tags: c#, string

I'm looking for a match in a string. If there is one, I take the sub-string before the first occurrence and the sub-string after the match.

Unfortunately, the second part of the process is throwing an exception. "**index and length must refer to a location within the string. parameter name length**"

```
string str1 = (firstIndex > 0) 
          ? line.Substring(0, firstIndex) : string.Empty;


string str3 = (lastIdx < line.Length - 1) 
    ? line.Substring(lastIdx + 1, line.Length - 1) : string.Empty;// This line
                                                                  //is causing problem
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: **MSDN** is your friend: [String.Substring Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documents one- and two-argument versions of `String.Substring()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take substring, you need to specify the length of the substring, not the index of the last character.

Instead of

```
line.Substring(lastIdx + 1, line.Length - 1)
```

try

```
line.Substring(lastIdx + 1, line.Length - (lastIdx + 1))
```

(or just omit the second parameter as @Selman22 suggested.)

Answer (score 2):

Second parameter of `Substring` is length. If you want to get substring starting from `lastIdx + 1` to the end of your string then just don't pass a lenght parameter. Use:

```
string str3 = (lastIdx < line.Length - 1) 
   ? line.Substring(lastIdx + 1) : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN, [String.Substring Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

This example shows the use of both the one- and two-argument versions of `String.Substring()`:

```cs
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var line = "stackoverflow";
        //               ^  ^
        //               a  b

        var firstIndex = 5;  // a
        var lastIndex = 8;   // b

        // Extracts "stack".
        string str1 = (firstIndex > 0)
            ? line.Substring(0, firstIndex) : string.Empty;

        // Extracts "flow".
        string str3 = (lastIndex < line.Length - 1)
            ? line.Substring(lastIndex + 1) : string.Empty;

        Console.WriteLine("first: [{0}]\nlast[{1}]\n", str1, str3);
    }
}
```